# Ionic 4 does not allow opening in new tab function

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, user-experience

We are building our [new site](https://2020.limundo.com/) with: Angular 7 / Ionic 4 *(and back-end PHP 7 / Laravel 5)*

The idea is to have one code base for web *(desktop/mobile)* as well as for Android/iOS app.

Problem - it won't *(on dekstop browsers/OS)* allow opening links in a new tab.
In some instances *(ie. Chrome/Mac OS X)* it does allow you to open the link in new tabs via right click menu *(see screenshot)*, but you can't use **keyboard/mouse shortcuts** *(ie. cmd + click on Mac or click on wheel/third button on Windows mouse)* which is a UX problem.

[Right click menu - screenshot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkJjG.jpg)

Comment: Why do you need to open link on a new tab? If I understood correctly you are saying that right click to open is working but Ctrl + click to open in new tab is not working consistently, is that right? It is because of JavaScript captures your clicks. Check following [question](https://superuser.com/q/927585/1149636) to know more.

Comment: It is not a must, but current site setup breaks the browser behavior (ie. I am looking for several items and would like to compare them - opening in a new tab is a good solution offered by browsers.

Tested the solution - but with it the complete site won't load (JS needed for Angular and Ionic front-end).

Comment: Of course JS is required and disabling it won't be an option for you but the issue you are facing is because of how JS behaves in certain browsers. If you want you can use middle click as it seems to work most of the time, which is mentioned in the link I shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We, inadvertently found a solution - by switching to Ionic 5 we changed the layout so that we use web components in critical fields, instead of Ionic components.
It was for other purposes, but it solved this issue.

Comment: In fact, even better, it turns out we can still use the Ionic components, but just reorder it in the code what will be loaded in what order.